# Why does a helper rerun when not referenced to any reactive variables inside a #with-block?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

Why does the helper `insideWith` inside the `#with`-block gets recomputed when `foo` changes? The helper is not referencing any reactive data source!

**foo.js**

```
var foo;

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  foo = new ReactiveVar();
  foo.set(0);
  Template.board.helpers({
    obj: function() {
      return {
        foo: foo.get()
      };
    },
    insideWith: function() {
      return console.log('insideWith');
    },
    fooInsideWith: function() {
      foo.get();
      return console.log("fooInsideWith ");
    },
    notInsideWith: function() {
      return console.log('notInsideWith');
    },
    fooNotInsideWith: function() {
      foo.get();
      return console.log("fooNotInsideWith ");
    }
  });
  Template.board.events({
    'click button': function(e, t) {
      return foo.set(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
    }
  });
}
```

**foo.html**

```
<body>
    {{> bar}}
</body>

<template name="bar">
    <div class="bar">
        <button>Random</button>
        <div>
            {{#with obj}}
                {{insideWith}}
                {{fooInsideWith}}
            {{/with}}
        </div>

        <div>
            <span>{{obj.foo}}</span>
            {{notInsideWith}}
            {{fooNotInsideWith}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Huh? `foo` is a reactive data source. `foo = new ReactiveVar();`

Comment: yes, but insideWith doesn't use it. it only prints to the console.

Comment: You have `{{#with obj}}`. `obj` is a helper that you defined that returns something based on the reactive var `foo`

Comment: what does that have to do with the `insideWith` helper? elaborate on that please!

Comment: `{{#with}}` will run automatically whenever `obj` changes because `obj` is a helper with the reactive data source `foo`. `{{insideWith}}` is nested inside of `{{#with}}`, so obviously it runs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the comments (@fuzzybabybunny):

{{#with}} will run automatically whenever obj changes because obj is a helper with the reactive data source foo. {{insideWith}} is nested inside of {{#with}}, so obviously it runs as well.